# Use a logger during configuration

Tags: azure-functions, .net-7.0

Is it possible to get an ILogger object during the startup? Please see the code:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()    
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder) =>
    {
       // write to the log stream here?
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a logger to use only in configuration using `LoggerFactory`.

Something like:

```cs
// ...
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
// ...

var logger = LoggerFactory
    .Create(builder => 
        builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information)
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug())
    .CreateLogger<Program>();

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => {
        logger.LogInformation("Something");
    })
    .Build();
// ...
```

In [*Serilog* documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#serilogaspnetcore---) a similar approach is used in setting up log for web applications startup. A "temporary" logger is used until the log configuration is not completed.

Comment: This seems to work, but I cannot see the log output in the Azure Funciton - Log stream. How can I make it appear there?

Comment: Try to add `.AddDebug()` after the `.AddConsole()` (updated the answer). I found in [Enable streaming execution logs in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/streaming-logs) "This is equivalent to the output seen when you debug your functions during local development and when you use the Test tab in the portal", so may be that the Log Stream intercept the _Debug_ logger.

Comment: I added `.AddDebug()`, but output is still not showing in Log stream.

Comment: If you are using Application Insights, I imagine you need to add the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService package as specified in [Application Insights for Worker Service applications (non-HTTP applications)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service). I tried but I didn't find a working configuration for it.

Comment: Try using Serilog with specific [sink](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights), probably it is easier to set up.